# Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When i ran startFabric command i got this error

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker
>   build: Error returned from build: 2 "# github.com/fabcar/go:

Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

Is it properly downloaded?check with command `docker ps` .

If possible remove all the dangling containers and run again.The commands you can use are as below.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker stop $(docker images -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

To remove dangling containers

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q --filter "dangling=true")
```